# How could I make vim change the current working directory automatically?

Tags: vim

Every time I log in with the username `debian8` and open a file (whose path is `/home/debian8/Desktop/homework/test.txt`) with Vim,  the `:pwd` command returns `/home/debian8`

How could I make `/home/debian8/Desktop/homework` the current directory? So I don't have to resort to `:cd /home/debian8/Desktop/homework` to change it after opening the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`:help 'autochdir'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27autochdir%27)

> When on, Vim will change the current working directory whenever you open a file, switch buffers, delete a buffer or open/close a window. It will change to the directory containing the file which was opened or selected. **Note**: When this option is on some plugins may not work.

Answer (score -4):

1. Navigate to your project directory:

   ```
   $ cd Desktop/homework/
   ```
2. Edit your file:

   ```
   $ vim test.txt
   ```

Comment: why not set autochdir in the configuration file?

Comment: Because it's just as useless as downvoting answers you don't understand. Why don't you learn to use your system instead of asking silly questions?

Comment: I have give the answer as you provide it :cd /home/debian8/Desktop/homework to change it after opening the file,you copy my answer,so it is right for me to downvote your answer.it is no relationship with asking silly question.

Comment: You don't deserve any help.